# Windows 8: SSL certificate binding fails both programmatically and through netsh

Tags: ssl, binding, windows-8, certificate, port

We have an application that auto-generates a certificate and binds it, using httpapi, to a selected port. Under Windows 7, and 2003/2008 Servers this works like a charm. The certificate can also be rebound to other ports by un-binding, then binding to the new port.

Under Windows 8, however, only unbinding from the old port succeeds. An attempt to bind the certificate to the new port value fails with error code 1312 revealing the message "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

What's odd here is that when trying to add a bound certificate through **netsh** it also fails, in elevated console, with the same error and message ("SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312|A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."), regardless to the port number.

To add suspense, the application has an installer that initially binds the certificate on install, and unbinds it on uninstall. And this thing never fails! The installer works in "Windows 7" operating system context, while the application is under "Windows Vista", if this can be a clue. The console is under "Windows 8" context.

Has anyone had a similar problem under this OS? Any ideas why this might be happening?

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our certificate generating code, we used X509Store class' methods to add the certificate to the store. Under Windows 8 this rendered the certificate "untrusted" even if the application was run as administrator. The cause might be either different implementation of the class in .NET 4.5 or imposed limitations due to the OS context the application was running in.

Solved the problem by invoking "certutil.exe" through a Process class to add the certificate to the store.